# Select element by (new) ID from AJAX response with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to select an element with an ID that was not in the HTML page prior to an AJAX update?

Example (semi-pseudo code and much simpler than the code I have the problem with):

The page is loaded and contains this div:

```
<div id="divToUpdateWithAJAX">
    <button onclick="hideElement('oldID')"></button>
    <element id="oldID"></element>
</div>
```

Then I call an AJAX function to update the div to this

```
<div id="divToUpdateWithAJAX">
    <button onclick="hideElement('newID')"></button>
    <element id="newID"></element>
</div>
```

The javascript function:

```
hideElement(id)
{
    $('#' + id).fadeOut();
}
```

When I view the page source in Chrome after the AJAX update I can not see the change (newID is not there, it is still oldID etc.). According to what I have read, this is normal.

In my case the $('#' + id) (when id = 'newID') does not give me the element. Is this normal?

Comment: please post your ajax call

Comment: view source or inspect element?